# Spawning mouse cursor on second monitor when Alt-Tabbing

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, monitor

I play CSGO in full screen windowed settings on my primary screen and have another game running on my second monitor. How can I make it so that when I Alt-Tab out of my CSGO game my cursor spawns on my second monitor with the other game running instead of spawning in the middle of my primary screen? Now I have to keep dragging it to my second monitor, which is kind of annoying since I have to do it pretty much every 30 seconds. When I click Alt-Tab on my second monitor it does return to CSGO however, but not the other way around.

Comment: You could probably have some sort of a script do this, but that's out of scope for Arqade. The reason the cursor "spawns" in the center of your primary screen is because CSGO has it locked in the center, so it's not able to leave the game window area while playing.

Comment: The solution to this issue is, play both games on same monitor

Comment: Also be careful with 3rd party software. VAC may not like it.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever reads this and wants this too: I downloaded Displayfusion software and set  a Trigger to move my mouse cursor to the center of my other monitor when the game is focused (so when Alt-Tabbing).